# Firebase distribution CLI command not working with jenkins

Tags: ios, firebase, jenkins, firebase-cli, firebase-app-distribution

I am using below firebase cli command to upload iOS app to firebase through Jenkins but it is saying firebase command not found. But if I am using the same command through Mac terminal, it's working successfully. So can you please let me know do I need to install any Jenkins plugin to make firebase command work for Jenkins. Your help would be appreciated.

firebase appdistribution:distribute test.ipa  \
    --app 1:1234567890:ios:0a1b2c3d4e5f67890  \
    --release-notes "Bug fixes and improvements" --testers-file testers.txt

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue earlier. Fixed by setting firebase path under **Manage Jenkins> Configure System > Environment variables** with key PATH+EXTRA